# jQuery Tabs manual activation

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

How can I activate a particular tab programmatically? I tried the following code after reading online jQuery docs:

```
$("#MyTabsDiv").tabs( "option", "active", 1 );
```

This does bring up the specified tab contents, but it doesn't highlight the selected tab's header, which is what happens when I manually click on the tab header. I have tried the "refresh" option too, without any success. I am using Bootstrap 3's TAB css on top of jQuery's tabs()

Comment: You could just fire a click event on the desired tab.  Kinda hackey, but I think it would work.

Comment: You could achieve that via css: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707224/how-to-highlight-selected-jquery-ui-tab

Comment: Thanks everyone. I forgot to mention that I was using Bootstrap 3's TAB css on top of jQuery's tabs(), which was causing the problem. @KennyThompson's simply hack did the trick for me.

Comment: Another solution that adds active class (for bootstrap tabs) when new tab is activated. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25553465/1342440

Comment: Bootstrap has its own jQuery plugin for their tabs FYI (you probably knew that, just pointing it out in case you didn't).

Comment: @KennyThompson: Can't thank you enough. I had mixed up Bootstrap's and jQuery-UI's Tab mechanisms without knowing. Things look much, much better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Bootstrap's CSS for tabs uses a class of `active`, add class when tab is activated  - [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8c7nje32/3/)

```
$( "#MyTabsDiv" ).tabs({
    activate: function( event, ui ) {
        $(ui.newTab).addClass('active')
        $(ui.oldTab).removeClass('active')  
    }
});
```

or attach to event using on() - **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8c7nje32/4/)**

```
$("#MyTabsDiv").on( "tabsactivate", function( event, ui ) {
    $(ui.newTab).addClass('active')
    $(ui.oldTab).removeClass('active')  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hack a user manually clicking the tab by firing a `.click()` event on the desired tab.

You can also see [bootstrap's own jQuery plugin to manage your tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs) .

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the CSS:

```
#tabs .ui-tabs-active {
  background: yellow;
}
```

[::source::](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707224/how-to-highlight-selected-jquery-ui-tab)